# find coordinate A from equation of the tangent and the gradient

Tags: calculus, tangent-line

Q. The tangent to the curve $y=x^3-3x^2+x$ makes an angle of $\theta = 45^\circ$ with the positive direction of the $x$-axis
Establish the coordinates of point $A$.

$$m=\tan\theta\\
m=\tan(45)\\
m=1$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = m\\
\frac{dy}{dx} =1\\
\frac{dy}{dx}= 3x^2-6x+1\\
1=3x^2-6x+1\\
0=3x^2-6x\\
6x=3x^2\\
x=\frac{3x^2}{6}$$

Not sure what do to after this point?

Comment: *this is only for higher maths level (sqa)

Comment: What is the point $A$?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to edit the post and make it readable for others.

Comment: The next steps would be to recall how to simplify fractions, and to remember what one has learned about solving quadratic equations.

Comment: Please do not use tags you don't understand. This is not vector analysis, differential topology, or ordinary differential equations.

Comment: oops didn’t realise the tags had changed from what i had typed in!!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not with figuring out the tangent, its with algebra manipulation.

You have correctly figured out $3x^2−6x = 0$,

But why do this: $3x^2 = 6x$

, when you can **factor** to find solutions: $$3x^2−6x = 0 \to 3x(x−2) = 0$$

Hence, either, $x = 0, x - 2 = 0$, which gives the values for $x$: $x = {0, 2}$

Suggest reading... [Factoring](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/factoring.html) ... [Factoring Quadratics](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/factoring-quadratics.html) ... [Solving equations](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/equations-solving.html)

Answer (score 0):

Can be solved directly using differential calculus  only.

( slope is the same as derivative at the required point.)

$$ y = 3x^3-3x^2+x$$
$$ y'(x)=9x^2-6x +1 =1\to x(3 x -2)=0$$

There are ***two points*** with slope =1.

$ x=(0, \frac{2}{3});$
The corresponding y values are
$ y=(0,\frac{2}{9});$
[image]